# Write a function called ablmt that takes one character as an input argument (the function does not have to check the format of the input), returns one

Tags: matlab

***Problem 10.*** Write a function called ablmt that takes one character as an
input argument (the function does not have to check the format of the input),
returns one string as an output argument. It uses a three-branch switchstatement
to set its output argument to “MATLAB”, if the input character is
one of the characters in the string, “MATLAB”, or set its output argument to
“matlab” if the character is one of the characters in the string, “matlab”, or set
its output argument to “I just don’t have it in me”, if the character is in neither
name.

I tried to do the following but it does not give me the function I want, I get error:

```
function ablmt(x)
M=1;m=2;A=3;a=4;T=5;t=6;L=7;l=8;B=9;b=10;
switch x
    case 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 9
        disp('MATLAB');
    case 2 || 4 || 6 || 8 || 10
        disp('matlab');
    otherwise
        disp('I just don’t have it in me');
end
end
```

Could anyone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @AndrewFan 
I think the error is that the function I have to put a letter of the word matlab and I do not know how to put characters, I get error "variable not defined." How can I make Matlab accept characters as input variables? Thank you.

Comment: in the MATLAB console, try to call your function `ablmt('a')`